# Extracting a single cell value from multiple csv files in R and

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have 500 csv. files with data that looks like:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnvvR.png)

I want to extract one cell (e.g. B4 or **0.477**) per a csv file and combine those values into a single csv. What are some recommendations on how to do this easily?

Comment: What about reading one file per time into a `data.frame`, accessing the required cell and storing it somewhere?

Comment: @BrunoZamengo there's no point reading all the file

Comment: see `?read.table`. the skip and nrows arguments will be useful. You could also use `scan`, which takes both of those (nlines instead of nrows) arguments and is a little more fine tuned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
all.fi <- list.files("/path/to/csvfiles", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)  # store names of csv files in path as a string vector
library(readr)  # package for read_lines and write_lines
ans <- sapply(all.fi, function(i) { eachline <- read_lines(i, n=4)  # read only the 4th line of the file
                        ans <- unlist(strsplit(eachline, ","))[2]  # split the string on commas, then extract the 2nd element of the resulting vector
                        return(ans) })
write_lines(ans, "/path/to/output.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment. So, I will write my comment here.

Since your data is very large and it is very difficult to load it individually, then try this: [Importing multiple .csv files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r). It is similar to the first part of your problem. For second part, try this:

You can save your data as a `data.frame` (as with the comment of @Bruno Zamengo) and then you can use `select` and `merge` functions in R. Then, you can easily combine them in single `csv` file. With `select` and `merge` functions you can select all the values you need and them combine them. I used this idea in my project.  Do not forget to use `lapply`.